# Problem in opening Excel files externally during execution of a C# application

Tags: c#, excel

I have created a C# application whose inputs are some large Excel files.

In my code, I open it, process and then close it. The whole process takes some 15-20 minutes. During this time when I try to open some other Excel files(1) externally, anyone of the input Excel files(2) (which is currently being processed) is also getting opened along with this. When I try to close this(2), exception occurs and the tool aborts its process.

I think the problem occurs because the Excel files are opened under the same instance. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to start the excel file open process?

Comment: Have you evr tried to use one of the 3rd party components to read from Excel. See http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/reading-and-writing-excel-files-with.html. Excel API is great but it also very memory/processor consuming approach

Comment: The following is the code: ApplicationClass objApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass(); Workbook objWb = objApp .Workbooks.Open("File Name",0, true, 1, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,Type.Missing, false, false, 0,true); Worksheet objWs = (Worksheet) objWb.Worksheets.get_Item(1); //process GC.Collect(); objWb.Close(false, strDictFile, false); objApp.Workbooks.Close(); objApp.Quit(); ReleaseComObject(objWs); ReleaseComObject(objWb); ReleaseComObject(objApp); objWs = null; objWb = null; objApp= null; GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Comment: What kind of application is this? Winforms or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code:

```
Excel.ApplicationClass objExcelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
Excel.Workbook objWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("File Name",0, true, 1, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,Type.Missing, false, false, 0,true);
Excel.Worksheet objWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet) objWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Excel.Range objRangeData =objWorksheet.UsedRange;
// Some proces
GC.Collect();
objRangeData.Clear ();
objWorkbook.Close(false, strDictFile, false);
objExcelApp.Workbooks.Close();
objExcelApp.Quit();             
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objRangeData); 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objWorksheet);          
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objWorkbook); System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objExcelApp); 
objWorksheet = null; 
objWorkbook = null; 
objExcelApp = null; 
GC.Collect(); 
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: Sorry this is not the answer. I was trying to answer phoenix's question.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will open only the workbooks you want it to open and in most cases runs much faster than using the Excel COM Interop APIs from .NET.

You can see samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC